# DynamicILInfo call method

Tags: .net, debugging, dynamicmethod

So I'm playing arround with debugging in .NET. 
And I am trying to call a method with DynamicILInfo from a dll.
But what am I doing wrong?

```
      delegate void assinv1();
    private static void insert()
    {
        MethodInfo entryPoint = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(@"method.dll")).EntryPoint;
        Type[] args = new Type[] { typeof(string[]) };
        DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod("assinv", null, null);
        DynamicILInfo dynamicILInfo = dm.GetDynamicILInfo();
        SignatureHelper localVarSigHelper = SignatureHelper.GetLocalVarSigHelper();
        localVarSigHelper.AddArguments(args, null, null);
        dynamicILInfo.SetLocalSignature(localVarSigHelper.GetSignature());
        dynamicILInfo.SetCode(entryPoint.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray(), entryPoint.GetMethodBody().MaxStackSize);
        assinv1 d1 = dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(assinv1)) as assinv1;
        d1();
    }
    }
```

Comment: How is the code not working? Are you getting some exception? If yes, could you post the whole exception?

Comment: @Justus Show the original method code. And I dont see that you call to SetCode() at all

Comment: @svick   I'm sorry for the short question without any info. I'm getting this exception: " Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program."  I've edited the function also. Look OP.

Comment: It looks to me like you're not just trying to call a method, you're trying to create a copy of a method from another assembly and call that. Could you explain why? Can't you just use reflection (without `DynamicMethod`) to get the delegate?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that the bytes in the array you are copying resolve only to opcodes that are valid within the assembly they are coming from.

An opcode for a call to a method does not refer to the high level MethodInfo of that method but to a meta token that is basically an index into a method table specific for that assembly. Even the original source code compiled twice could result in different token values.

The solution to this is much more complex than a simple copy. You need to look up the meta token in the original assembly and reinterpret it in your execution context (your current assembly).

Comment: As svick in his comment pointed out, if all you want is a delegate to call, you should use reflections.